# filter data by a column in datagrid using combobox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, filter, datagridview, combobox

I'm trying to filter by the stats column, which contains 3 types of data "valid", "out of use" and "request purchase", but I'm not able to filter by the three, when I try to filter only by one it works, but the three together don't filters none.if anyone can help me what is the problem with the code

code:

```
private void combo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            if (combo.SelectedIndex == 1) ;
            DataView pp = (dtgridreagentes.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView;
            pp.RowFilter = string.Format("Stats = '{0}'", "Válido");

            if (combo.SelectedIndex == 2) ;
            DataView rr = (dtgridreagentes.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView;
            rr.RowFilter = string.Format("Stats = '{0}'", "Fora de uso");

            if (combo.SelectedIndex == 3) ;
            DataView tt = (dtgridreagentes.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView;
            tt.RowFilter = string.Format("Stats = '{0}'", "Solicitar compra");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an obvious bug in your code.

There is no {} after your if, you should write your code in a code block.

If you run your code, only the last 2 lines of code will work.

Correctly modify this question:

```
if (combo.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    DataView pp = (dtgridreagentes.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView;
    pp.RowFilter = string.Format("Stats = '{0}'", "Válido");
}
```

Comment: it worked thanks, I had not noticed that bug